# Carousel.Item doesn't render anything when inside loop

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have below carousel in react js which works as expected when I individually define all 3 Carousel.Item but the same doesn't work inside the loop.

```
<Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} className="carousel">
                {carouselItems.map((item, index) => {
                    console.log('item ' + JSON.stringify(item));
                    <Carousel.Item key={index}>
                        <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src="/images/moon.jpg"
                            alt={item.heading}
                        />
                        <Carousel.Caption>
                            <h3>{item.heading}</h3>
                            <p>{item.brief}</p>
                        </Carousel.Caption>
                        </Carousel.Item>
                    })}
</Carousel>
```

in console log I can see the data coming as expected but still nothing renders, can anyone please suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to work you need to `return` from your `map`:

```
<Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        className="carousel"
      >
        {carouselItems.map((item, index) => {
          console.log("item " + JSON.stringify(item));
          // you forgot to return the Carousel.Item here:
          return (
            <Carousel.Item key={index}>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="/images/moon.jpg"
                alt={item.heading}
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>{item.heading}</h3>
                <p>{item.brief}</p>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but why the same was not working with forEach loop?

Comment: You are welcome. `forEach` in javascript doesn't return a new array but only iterates over the elements in the array. This is why you have to use `map` and make sure you  `return` from each iteration - in order to get an array of components (`Carousel.Item`s in your case) to render.